# Change the string in an alert box only after an input button’s value has changed, using JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a sample of my code. The synopsis is this:

1. User enters email address into email field.
2. User clicks "Submit" button.
3. An alert box reading, "Email address has been added to database!" displays.
4. User clicks "OK" in that alert box.
5. The "Submit" button changes to "Submitted!".
6. User clicks "Submitted!" button.
7. An alert box reading, "You have already submitted your email address!" displays.

The last step, showing a different alert box, is where I am having trouble.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>This is the code used to create a field and submit button.</title>
</head> 
<body>

<!--The below code is creating a field and submit button-->
    <label id= "email_field_text" for="email_field"> Input your email to subscribe to funny comics and memes by yours truly</label>
    <input id="email_field" type="email" placeholder="--->  Enter Your Email Here  <---">
    <input type="Submit" Id="emailsubmitbutton" style="background-color: green" value="Submit" onClick= "myfunction()" required="required">



<!--The below code is changing the Submit" button to "Submitted!" once clicked and also showing an alert box.-->
       <script>
            function myfunction() {
           document.getElementById("emailsubmitbutton").value= "Submitted!";
      alert("Email address has been added to database!");
}

//Code in this space will display an alert box once a user clicks the "Submittted!" button. The alert box will display the following string: "You have already submitted your email address!".-->
      </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmm... There's no form to submit ..?

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand what you mean. My goal is not to submit a form, or really anything at all at this point. A value will be entered into the Email field, but not saved to any database. What I am focused on at this point is to display another alert box after the user clicks the submit button for a second time.

Comment: Then use a button type of `button` instead of `submit`. Create a flag variable outside of the function, and mark it as "submitted" when the "form" is "submitted", then check the flag.

Comment: You'll have to excuse my ignorance. As I am considerably new to programming, I do not follow what you are saying in regard to "flag variable". I would also like a low level explanation of why using a button type of button is preferred over a button type of submit.

Comment: Submit button is used to submit a form, and you don't have a form. Using correct type of a button you can avoid some unexpected behavior, like page reload. For a flag, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mr Geek is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50591137/578288) that you should use an `if` statement to run a different `alert` statement after the user has already submitted an email.

However, rather than checking DOM nodes (the representation of your page’s HTML elements) to see the state of your program, it is cleaner to store state in variables. In your case, you can store a boolean variable `hasSubmitted` that is `false` at first but gets set to `true` when the user submits their email.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>This is the code used to create a field and submit button.</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!--The below code is creating a field and submit button-->
  <label id="email_field_text" for="email_field"> Input your email to subscribe to funny comics and memes by yours truly</label>
  <input id="email_field" type="email" placeholder="--->  Enter Your Email Here  <---">
  <input type="Submit" Id="emailsubmitbutton" style="background-color: green" value="Submit" onClick="myfunction()" required="required">


  <!--The below code is changing the Submit" button to "Submitted!" once clicked and also showing an alert box.-->
  <script>
    var hasSubmittedYet = false;
    function myfunction() {
      var submitButton = document.getElementById("emailsubmitbutton");
      if (!hasSubmittedYet) {
        submitButton.value = "Submitted!";
        hasSubmittedYet = true;
        alert("Email address has been added to database!");
      } else {
        alert("You have already submitted your email address!");
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

By the way, you could improve your interface by disabling the email address `input` after submitting the email, to make it clear that you can’t change the email after it was submitted:

```
var emailField = document.getElementById("email_field");
emailField.disabled = true;
```

That would go in the first branch (`true` branch) of `if (!hasSubmittedYet) {`.

Answer (score 2):

Although this isn't a great way to check for submission, I would suggest using an if to test for the value of the button, like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>This is the code used to create a field and submit button.</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!--The below code is creating a field and submit button-->
  <label id="email_field_text" for="email_field"> Input your email to subscribe to funny comics and memes by yours truly</label>
  <input id="email_field" type="email" placeholder="--->  Enter Your Email Here  <---">
  <input type="Submit" Id="emailsubmitbutton" style="background-color: green" value="Submit" onClick="myfunction()" required="required">



  <!--The below code is changing the Submit" button to "Submitted!" once clicked and also showing an alert box.-->
  <script>
    function myfunction() {
      var submitButton = document.getElementById("emailsubmitbutton");
      if (submitButton.value !== "Submitted!") {
        submitButton.value = "Submitted!";
        alert("Email address has been added to database!");
      } else {
        alert("You have already submitted your email address!");
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```